# What exactly is "change" in the rep leagues?

Tags: support, reputation

As seen in this screenshot:

[image]

I have more "change" than I have "total reputation". What is this "change", and why is it so much higher than my total reputation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your change in rank, not in reputation.

You can confirm this by changing the Sort Order to by Rank Change and seeing that number is the one in order.